# how to view longbob image in fpdf?

Tags: php, image, mysqli, blob, fpdf

here is my code -> progress-report.php 
data type is longblob, Api is FPDF

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT school_logo FROM dsms_school_img");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
  $logo = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['school_logo'] ).'"/>';
}
```

when i put this `$logo` in `$pdf->Image($logo,10,10,188);` it show this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4QECRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEPAAIAAAAGAAAAPgEQAAIAAAAPAAAARIKaAAUAAAABAAAAU4dpAAQAAAABAAAAWwAAAABDYW5vbgBDYW5vbiBFT1MgMTAwRAAAAAABAAAAoAAHgpoABQAAAAEAAACxgp0ABQAAAAEAAAC5iCcAAwAAAAIAZAAAkAMAAgAAABQAAADBkgkAAwAAAAIAEAAAkgoABQAAAAEAAADVpDQAAgAAAB0AAADdAAAAAQAAAKAAAAA4AAAACjIwMTc6MDE6MDYgMTY6MDc6MDkAAAAANwAAAAFFRi1TMTgtNTVtbSBmLzMuNS01LjYgSVMgU1RNAP/bAEMABQMEBAQDBQQEBAUFBQYHDAgHBwcHDwsLCQwRDxISEQ8RERMWHBcTFBoVEREYIRgaHR0fHx8TFyIkIh4kHB4fHv/bAEMBBQUFBwYHDggIDh4UERQeHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHv/AABEIAVQB/gMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAdAAACAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAADBAIFAAEGBwgJ/8QAQhAAAQQBAwMDAgQDBgQEBgMAAQACAxEEBRIhBjFBE1FhInEHFDKBI5GhFUJiscHwCFLR4RYkM1NDcoKDkvEXY6L/xAAbAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwABBAUGB//EADMRAAICAQQBAwIFAQgDAAAAAAABAgMRBBIhMUEFE1EiYRQycYHw0RUjQpGhscHhM1Lx/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD6O1LUA9xLqBXNaplsddPSmo55t1OVFlZu4nlfKXlnt6oRqWEEz5zzTrVNPLRW in C:\xampp\htdocs\dignitysmslatest\admin\Module\manage\pdf\fpdf.php on line 271
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory image support

Informations

Author: Olivier
License: FPDF
Description

This script allows to display images that are loaded in memory without the need of temporary files. There are two main uses:

- When an image is loaded from a database
- When an image is created with GD

For an image loaded into a string:

MemImage(string data [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, mixed link]]]]])

For a GD image:

GDImage(resource im [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, mixed link]]]]])

where im is the GD identifier. If you use JpGraph, you can retrieve it via a call to $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER).

```
$query = "SELECT school_logo FROM dsms_school_img";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $image = $row['imageField'];

    $pdf->MemImage($image, 50, 30);
```

Comment: Why did you answer question which is using `mysqli`, with `mysql` example?